# Changed some drawables, and now get FATAL EXCEPTION when I test on older android device

Tags: android

I have been designing an android app for API 7 to API 19, and it had been working well until I changed one of the drawables to a more appealing background (for several EditTexts).  The error is below.

```
05-09 07:00:43.129  13022-13022/vanwert.sdb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.VerifyError: vanwert.sdb.SerialDilution$1
        at vanwert.sdb.SerialDilution.onCreate(SerialDilution.java:134)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code up to the error is below.  The error occurs on the last line in this code (line 134).  I've removed the remaining code.  If I run the app on my new device, the Galaxy Note 3, it works well.  If I run it on the old Galaxy Vibrant (android 2.3 I believe) it gives this error.  Please help.  Thanks.

```
package vanwert.sdb;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.method.TextKeyListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.text.InputFilter.*;
import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class SerialDilution extends Activity {




    EditText    CDA, CDB, CDC, CDD, CDE, CDF, CDG, CDH, CDI, CDJ,
            CDK, CDL, CDM, CDN, CDO, CSB, CSC, CSD, CSE, CSF,
            CSG, CSH, CSI, CSJ, CSK, CSL, CSM, CSN, CSO,
            RVA, RVB, RVC, RVD, RVE, RVF, RVG, RVH, RVI, RVJ,
            RVK, RVL, RVM, RVN, RVO, TVNA, TVNB, TVNC, TVND,
            TVNE, TVNF, TVNG, TVNH, TVNI, TVNJ, TVNK, TVNL,
            TVNM, TVNN, TVNO, VCSB, VCSC, VCSD, VCSE, VCSF,
            VCSG, VCSH, VCSI, VCSJ, VCSK, VCSL, VCSM, VCSN,
            VCSO, VDLB, VDLC, VDLD, VDLE, VDLF, VDLG, VDLH,
            VDLI, VDLJ, VDLK, VDLL, VDLM, VDLN, VDLO;

    String CDAs, CDBs, CDCs, CDDs, CDEs, CDFs, CDGs, CDHs, CDIs, CDJs, CDKs, CDLs, CDMs, CDNs, CDOs,
            RVAs, RVBs, RVCs, RVDs, RVEs, RVFs, RVGs, RVHs, RVIs, RVJs, RVKs, RVLs, RVMs, RVNs, RVOs,
            CSBs, CSCs, CSDs, CSEs, CSFs, CSGs, CSHs, CSIs, CSJs, CSKs, CSLs, CSMs, CSNs, CSOs,TVNAs,
            TVNBs, TVNCs, TVNDs, TVNEs, TVNFs, TVNGs, TVNHs, TVNIs, TVNJs, TVNKs, TVNLs, TVNMs, TVNNs,
            TVNOs, VCSBs, VCSCs, VCSDs, VCSEs, VCSFs, VCSGs, VCSHs, VCSIs, VCSJs, VCSKs, VCSLs, VCSMs,
            VCSNs, VCSOs, VDLBs, VDLCs, VDLDs, VDLEs, VDLFs, VDLGs, VDLHs, VDLIs, VDLJs, VDLKs, VDLLs,
            VDLMs, VDLNs, VDLOs;

    String currentLanguage;

    HorizontalScrollView HScrollView;

    ScrollView MainScrollView;


    Double CSBi, CSCi, CSDi, CSEi, CSFi, CSGi, CSHi, CSIi, CSJi, CSKi, CSLi, CSMi, CSNi, CSOi;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_calculator);

    // set scrollview to start on left

        CDA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CDA);
        CDA.requestFocus();




    // setting input type based on language
        CSB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSB);
        CSC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSC);
        CSD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSD);
        CSE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSE);
        CSF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSF);
        CSG = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSG);
        CSH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSH);
        CSI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSI);
        CSJ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSJ);
        CSK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSK);
        CSL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSL);
        CSM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSM);
        CSN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSN);
        CSO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CSO);





        CSB.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSC.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSD.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSE.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSF.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSG.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSH.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSI.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSJ.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(1) });
        CSK.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(2) });
        CSL.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(2) });
        CSM.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(2) });
        CSN.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(2) });
        CSO.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new LengthFilter(2) });



        Button Calc;
    Calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcButton);
    Calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Here's some of my XML, but the entire file exceeds the character limit here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalcButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/goodbutton"
        android:text=" " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CSVButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="@drawable/csvbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CalcButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Comment: What size is your background?

Comment: Do you mean the file size?  I have background drawables on all my cells in a table. The table has 90 cells, each with a drawable in the background.  I changed one of the rows to have a nicer looking background image (15 cells), and now I get this error.

Comment: The background on my main activity is 132 kb.  Could that be an issue for older devices?  I really thought that was very small, but apparently it might not be.

Comment: I just changed the background for my main activity to white, and I still get the error when switching to the activity pasted in code above.  The only things that I did prior to the error were switching a row of the table to have a different drawable than the original, and switching a button to have different drawable backgrounds based on the language.  In other words, I've changed my resource files to have a different background for a specific button based on the language used by the user.

Comment: What's confusing is that the error is in the line for the button click, not when the actual drawables are loaded, which is prior to the button click of course.

Comment: Is it possible that the drawable for the button hasn't been found by the time the OnClickListener is called?  Do I need to add a delay.  I'm pretty much an amateur but this error only occurs on my older devide (Android 2.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.  I've solved this issue after much help from @Woodstown.  My code (hyperlinked in comments) declared all of my BigDecimal variables within the OnClick method.  When I instead declared all of those BigDecimal variables as global, prior to the OnClick method, the activity opened and ran smoothly on the older android device.  I'm sure there are other optimizations that Woodstown will be helping me with, but that worked perfectly for me.

For newbies like me, this is essentially what I mean:

Instead of:

```
package ......
import......

public class SerialDilution extends Activity {    

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            BigDecimal xyz;
              // do something with BigDecimal xyz
            BigDecimal abc;
              // do something with BigDecimal abc
```

Try:

```
package ......
import......

public class SerialDilution extends Activity {    

            BigDecimal xyz, abc;

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // now call method with BigDecimals xyx or abc
```

Simply declaring them together before the method fixed my issue with "arbitrarily rejecting large method" (as seen in Log level "Verbose" on logcat), and the Verify Error (seen in Log level "Error" on logcat).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html

If you are only getting the error with the lower API, then perhaps you are calling something in the onClick() method that is not supported in older versions. I have had similar problems when changing the background of a TextView dynamically.

I use this for backwards compatibility.

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    // old api
    setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    //newer api
    setBackground();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If this isn't your problem it might help to post your onClick() code.

Comment: What code do you have where it reads // old api and // newer api?  What are the differences between the codes that allow the program to function correctly at both lower and higher APIs?

Comment: See my edit, the new method setBackground() is not available in the older version.

Comment: Well, all my backgrounds are set in the XML file.  I'll upload it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, my xml would have exceeded the character limit, so I couldn't post much of that.

Comment: You are probably using some other method that it is not available in the older API versions. What is in your onClick method?

Comment: I'll post it when I get home.   However,  I'm wondering why this would be the issue if I haven't even clicked the button before the error.  The error occurs when I attempt to open the activity, so I don't have a chance to click the button.   Would the onClick method still be a possible issue in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to post enough characters to paste in my code after onClick.  Like I said, the only thing that I changed to create this error was a few drawables and I also added drawables to support other languages.  However, I am testing the app in the default language so I'm confused.

Comment: I suppose I could be wrong.  I tried a friends android phone and it might be a slightly different android version, so I am not 100% sure that this activity ever worked on my old android phone.  Is there a way I could post more code here and go past the character limit?

Comment: Here's a link to the entire activity code.  The setOnClickListener is fairly close to the top.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ebCBDJ6d7AMVUxdGktblhJYW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I found this in verbose:  05-11 01:14:44.443    4190-4190/vanwert.sdb W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: arbitrarily rejecting large method (regs=83 count=31902)
  05-11 01:14:44.443    4190-4190/vanwert.sdb W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lvanwert/sdb/SerialDilution$1;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
  05-11 01:14:44.443    4190-4190/vanwert.sdb W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier rejected class Lvanwert/sdb/SerialDilution$1;
05-11 01:14:44.443    4190-4190/vanwert.sdb D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-11 01:14:44.443    4190-4190/vanwert.sdb W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)

Comment: I have a feeling someone is going to tell me that my code is too cumbersome for the old android versions.  I hope this isn't the case.  I'm really new to programming in general.  I've been happy to get 3,400 downloads for my first app, but I'm still plagued by apparent mistakes when coding.  If you get a chance to see my hyperlinked code please let me know if you think its too complex and if there is a better way.  It is a lot of heavy calculations, and this was the best way I knew how to do it.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, bit of a time difference. I'll look through it now, but at a glance it seems very large for one class. I'll post again when I've looked through it.

Comment: Not a problem.  I've emailed you.